# Действие при смене анимации

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Как отследить момент смены анимации для выполнения метода из скрипта?
Есть система анимаций в Animator'е, меня интересует отслеживание перехода между анимациями Fall и Idle для воспроизведения звука приземления.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Причина следственная связь сломанная... Есть событие (причина) заставляющее проиграть анимацию преземление (следствие)... Почему воспроизведение звука должно быть следствием другого следствия, а не все той-же причины?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ решить проблему

```
bool temp;


void Update()
{
    if (!isGrounded)
    {
        temp = true;
    }

    if (temp)
    {
        LandControl();
    }
}

void LandControl()
{
    if (isGrounded)
    {
        sc.PlayLand();  //воспроизведение звука приземления
        temp = false;
    }
}
```